# How do I merge multiple of elements in string1 to one element in string2? C/C++

Tags: string, merge

I'm using C/C++, I have a problem with string.

I have a string `s1 = 'p^(qvr)<->~q'` and I want to merge 3 elements `s1[7] = '<', s1[8] = '-', s1[9] = '>'` into 1 element in string s2, which means that `s2 = p^(qvr)<->~q` but `s2[7] = '<->'`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, a string is an array of chars, thus accessing a string-element via [] gives you a single char. What you want is an array of strings, so just use a std::vector of std::string.